# 'procedure' not found (293)

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to run a procedure on appserver which is set up on localhost.

> **'testProc' was not found. (293)

```
    DEFINE VARIABLE hndle AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE tmp AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    CREATE SERVER hndle.

    PROCEDURE testProc:
        DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER o_tmp AS CHARACTER INITIAL "HELLO".
    END PROCEDURE.


    hndle:CONNECT ("-AppService AppServiceName-H localhost").
    RUN testProc ON hndle(OUTPUT tmp).


    hndle:DISCONNECT ().
    DELETE OBJECT hndle.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run internal procedures on an appserver. You have to put the code into its own .p file and run that on the appserver. The .p has to be available in the Propath of the appserver as well.

Comment: How do I make sure it's available in the appserver Propath?

Comment: I moved the procedure to another file and my appserver is running but when I try to run the procedure on it, it says " 'procedure.p' was not found (293).

Comment: Try qualifying it with full pathname for now. See if that works. But I would take some time to read up on AppServer configuration and administration. https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/oemcf/appserver-configuration-and-administration.html

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run the internal procedure 'testProc', not the procedure file 'testProc.p'. They have to be two separate files. Create a 'testProc.p' file on your appserver and put your logic in it:

```
DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER o_tmp AS CHARACTER INITIAL "HELLO".
```

In a separate file, put your code that calls testProc.p:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hndle AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE tmp AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

CREATE SERVER hndle.
hndle:CONNECT ("-AppService AppServiceName -H localhost").
RUN testProc.p ON hndle(OUTPUT tmp).

hndle:DISCONNECT ().
DELETE OBJECT hndle.

MESSAGE tmp VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION.
```

Note that your calling program is running testProc.p, not testProc. Run this code and you should get a pop-up message saying "HELLO".